# Laravel Eloquent Query Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, eloquent

The purpose of my application is to crunch payroll data by department, date(daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, and annually)  and display it in a dashboard with graphs.

I have two(2) tables that I upload CSV to obtain data: **'attendance'** and **'payroll'**;

I have ten(10) **schools** each identified by a four(4) digit number in a text field.

```
**attendance** = date | school_code | department_name | child_count

**payroll** = date | school_code | teacher_name | department | hours | pay_rate
```

---

Here's what I'm trying. My queries are terribly expensive.

```
public function index() {

    $schools     = array( '1001', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1007', '1008', '1009', '1010', '1011' );

    $infants   = 'Infants';
    $ones      = 'Ones';
    $twos      = 'Twos';
    $threes    = 'Threes';
    $fours     = 'Fours';
    $fives     = 'Fives';
    $schoolAge = 'School Age';
    $unknowns  = 'Unknown';
    $preK      = 'PreK';
    $office    = 'Office';

    $oneInfants    = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $infants );
    $oneOnes       = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $ones )->get();
    $oneTwos       = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $twos )->get();
    $oneThrees     = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $threes )->get();
    $oneFours      = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $fours )->get();
    $oneFives      = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $fives )->get();
    $oneSchoolAges = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $schoolAge )->get();
    $oneUnknowns   = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $unknowns )->get();
    $onePreK       = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $preK )->get();
    $oneOffice     = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schools[0] )->where( 'department_name', $office )->get();


... **REPEATED FOR EACH SCHOOL** ...


    $oneMaster= DB::table( 'payrolls' )
                    ->join( 'child_counts', 'child_counts.school_code', '=', 'payrolls.school_code' )
                    ->where( 'payrolls.department', $infants )
                    ->where('payrolls.school_code',$schools[0])
                    ->take( 100 )
                    ->select( 'payrolls.*', 'child_days' )
                    ->get();
```

---

I don't have a Model for schools because this is a third-party application with the data being exported CSV from our Main Operations Program.

---

How do I optimize these queries while joining on **school_code** between **child_counts** && **payrolls** - once I'm able to iterate through these schools, departments, and dates - I can query daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, and annually;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will benefit when using an actual Eloquent model for every database table you have (create a model for payrolls if you don't already have one).

Once you have the `Payroll` model, make sure the appropriate [relationship functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) are defined on each model. (Make a relationship on `ChildCount` and to make your life easier later on, also define the reversed relationship on `Payroll`).

**ChildCount.php**

```
public function payrolls() {
    return $this-hasMany(Payroll::class, 'school_code', 'school_code');
}

// I think you can even limit the payrolls in your relationship, not sure about this
public function payrollsLimited() {
    return $this-hasMany(Payroll::class, 'school_code', 'school_code')->limit(100);
}
```

This way you can leverage [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). This should get you started:

```
$schoolCode = $schools[0];
$departmentNames = [$infants, $ones, $twos, $threes]; // etc.
$childCounts = ChildCount::where( 'school_code', $schoolCode)
  ->whereIn( 'department_name', $departmentNames )
  ->with(['payrolls']) // assumes the ChildCount model has a relationship with the payroll model
  ->get();
```

The above could be wrapped in a foreach, to loop over each school, but of course you could load all the data for every school in one query as well. I don't know how many schools we're talking, or how big your payrolls table is, but if you'd want to try this, you would use `whereIn` instead of `where`.

Good luck!

PS: Last thing I want to add, is you might want to take another look at your database design or model names. It doesn't make sense to me that the `payrolls` and `childcounts` tables are joined via `school_code` (and is `ChildCount` the best name for your model?)

Comment: Thank you Pepijn.

Your response is thorough, informative, and pointed me in a much better direction.

Comment: Might you make a suggestion on how to join payrolls & child_counts? I assume I should make a **School** model - **school_code** and one **date** field are my common fields to work with. On which field should I join? 

We have nine(9) schools and payroll/attendance data going back two(2) years - upwards of apprx. 120,000 records :|

Thank you, again!

Comment: No problem, glad to help ! Yes, ideally you would create a `School` model (which will need a `schools` database table, so you'd have to import your csv into this [new table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations) first, for example using a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding)).
After adding the relationships on `School`, you can just loop over `School::with(['payrolls', 'childcounts'])->get()`. In this refactored scenario, `Payroll` and `ChildCount` probably shouldn't have a relationship to eachother anymore, because they are both related to the school, not really to eachother.

Comment: You've really been a huge help - thank you again :-)